# Use R to iteratively download all tiff files from shared Google Drive folder

Tags: r

I would like to use R to:
1) create a list of all tif files in a shared google drive folder
2) loop through list of files
3) save each file to local drive

I've tried [RGoogleDocs](http://thebiobucket.blogspot.ie/2014/03/download-all-documents-from-google.html) and [RGoogleData](https://r-forge.r-project.org/R/?group_id=519) and both seem to have stopped development and neither support downloading tif files. There is also [GoogleSheets](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/googlesheets/index.html), but again, it doesn't suit my needs. Does anyone know of a way to accomplish this task?

-cherrytree

Answer (score 0):

Here's a part of my code (cannot share all of it) that gets a list of urls and makes a copy on hard drive:

```
if (Download == TRUE) {
  urls = DataFrame$productimagepath

  for (url in urls) {
    newName <- paste ("Academy/",basename(url), sep =" ")
    download.file(url, destfile = newName, mode = "wb")
  }
}
```

Comment: A key part of the answer that is missing is how you created 'DataFrame$productimagepath'.